# Why is ml-engine functions present in Google Client API library instead of Google Cloud client library?

Tags: google-api-client, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tutorials/python-guide says ml-engine library in present in Google Client API library. Since Google Cloud client library is tailor-made for cloud applications, it should have had it no?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the client library is essentially autogenerated from REST API while the Google Cloud one is handwritten to follow idiomatic usage for each language.  So, usually the client API has wider language coverage and is immediately available. The Cloud API for specific languages are created if there is sufficient need.

So, I guess what I am saying is that you should provide feedback to the cloudml team on which language you'd like Google Cloud API for ml-engine.